# Elmah.axd on WebAPI 2.2 - No HTTP Resource was found

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, elmah, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm trying to access /elmah.axd in my broswer, but it returns:

```
{"message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://services.domain.com/elmah.axd'."}
```

The server is local (127.0.0.1) and even on that I have my web.config Elmah settings to secure it this way:

```
<elmah>
    <security allowRemoteAccess="true" />
</elmah>
```

My WebApiConfig looks like:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            // Locally only you will be able to see the exception errors
            config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.LocalOnly;

            // Web API routes
            config.Routes.IgnoreRoute("elmah", "elmah.axd");
            config.Routes.IgnoreRoute("allemah", "elmah.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            config.Routes.IgnoreRoute("elmahgeneric", "{resource}.axd/{*everything}");
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
            jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

            // Remove the XML formatter
            config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

I even tried ignoring only one route at the time from any of the 3 combinations and no luck.

finally my global.asax looks like this:

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

        }
```

Any hint or idea of what I could be missing, would be good.

Thanks in advance, really appreciate your time looking into this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I finally made it.

By adding to the WebApiConfig.cs file

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("AXD", "{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}", null, null, new StopRoutingHandler());
```

The entire code of the WebApiConfig.cs file looks like this:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            // Locally only you will be able to see the exception errors
            config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.LocalOnly;

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
            jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

            // Remove the XML formatter
            config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("AXD", "{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}", null, null, new StopRoutingHandler());

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }


    }
```

And the final change is add this to the global.asax under application_start method

```
RouteTable.Routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

Special thanks all who helped me with this issue.

Comment: Finally found a real answer of this weird problem, thanks @acido

Comment: This worked for me, but I only needed the `RouteTable.Routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");` in Applicaiton_Start.

Answer (score 5):

When I added the following in in the global.asax under the application_start method:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

It did not work until I put it above ...

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

The order of the routes that you add to the Routes property is significant, because the application uses the first route in the collection that matches the URL.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routetable.routes(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

The most likely problem is missing handlers to generate the error page.

Ensure the following handlers are configured your `web.config` file:

```
<system.web>
    ...
    <httpHandlers>
      ...
      <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
    </httpHandlers>


<system.webServer>
    ...
    <handlers>
      ...
      <add name="Elmah" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
    </handlers>
```

With those settings in place you should be able to access `elmah.axd` and secure it as expected.

You can grab a sample config file that was updated from a fresh project as an example here: https://brutaldev.com/download/30987439.zip

Comment: I found that I needed to move the Elmah handler to be the first entry in the handlers list.

Answer (score 2):

For me adding

```
config.Routes.IgnoreRoute("axd", "{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

to `WebApiConfig` was enough.